# How do I automatically add links on the right sidebar in drupal 7?

Tags: views, blocks

Let's say I have a few articles about weight training. How do I populate the right sidebar blocks with related links to current article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just implemented related content using views following [this tutorial](http://www.compago.it/manuali/35-utilita/345-how-to-create-a-related-block-with-drupal-7.html). If you prefer using a module you got even [more choices](http://drupal.org/node/323329).

Comment: hmmm my drupal 7 version doesn't have the views section.

Comment: Ah I think I need to install the views module

Comment: Awesome! It works! Now all related articles are displayed on the sidebar of any article! Thanks a ton!